# total_count method undefined for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I'm trying to use the total_count methods to count all of my products and display the number

```
@products.total_count
```

and this works just fine it gives me the total number of products and even work with the search results however when I click on a product it says

> undefined method `total_count' for nil:NilClass

Comment: You need to show more code. Clearly @products is not set in whatever code gets called when you 'click a product'.

Answer (score 1):

> however when I click on a product it says `undefined method`total_count' for nil:NilClass`

You'd be looking at `products#show` and typically setup a `@product` instance var.  As @99miles stated, `@products` does not exist at this point.

I'd suggest going with a [counter cache column (on Product) for performance reasons](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column).